# Matlab restoring the image to its original colors

Tags: image, matlab, rgb, restore

I asked it in the past, someone suggested me to use MACBETH but I don't have enough money for having it :/

[image]

So before I photographed, I've added 3 circles to the image to be places in the image: the first circle is red with RGB of [255 0 0], the second is green circle with RGB of [0 255 0] and the third is blue [0 0 255]. Thus I can see the change about the pixels average of each of them and fix the whole image by this change.

I have all the pixels of each circle. I made average of the pixels and I got the next thing:

The red circle's average RGB of its all contained pixels is [243 15 26].

the green circle's average RGB of its all contained pixels is [29 235 56].

and about the blue circle it is [14 33 250].

how can I fix the colors of each pixel in the image by the result of the new red\green\blue circles' RGB?

Comment: it is not clear what you want to do. What do you mean "the colors of each pixel in the image"? Which pixels do you refer to? Also what is the "new RGB"? The average RGB values from the circles? Is your problem replacing the circle-pixel values with their estimated average?

Comment: @gevang, I'm sorry. I tried to explain it again. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume a linear color mapping, you can construct a linear system that describes the change from original colors, e.g. (0, 0, 255) to observed colors, eg. (14, 33, 250).

Basically, y = A*x, where x is the original colors, y is the observed colors, A is the transformation matrix.

Once you calculated A, you can invert it to obtain the transform needed to go from y to x. You can then apply A^(-1) on all pixels for linear color correction.

Comment: this Transformation matrix is about the change of the green.
by the same way, I can find the Transformation matrix of the blue and red. How can I combine them all to one Transformation matrix? or maybe I don't need the combination?

Comment: No, it is a 3x3 matrix that operates 3-dimensional vectors, so it is one matrix for all R, G, B.

Comment: ok, I did what you suggest. I did: X = A^(-1) * Y  in order to get the "original" colors, but I got a negative values. what can I do with them? it's not good because the rgb can't be negative :/ thank you!

Comment: Sometimes the values fall out of range, either you normalize the value range afterwards or you cut off at 0 and 255. Maybe also sth. went wrong, how do the results look like in general?

Comment: the RGB of each pixel is [x y z], while 0 <= x,y,z <= 255.
after the use with the transformation matrix, I got pixels that look like:
[2 43 50]
[-78.25 65.24 33]
[2.54 3.1 2.31]
[-15.498 -120.63 23]
[230.42 -180.86 -1.64]

etc..
so what do you suggest me to do? round the elements that are smaller than 0 to be zero and the elements that are bigger than 255 to be 255? (I hope I understand you)..

Comment: Maybe your calculation does not work right. You could also try the linear system x=A*y directly.