# MATLAB: sort matrix by condition

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix

I want to sort a matrix of 3X3:

```
mat =
    129    14     20
    42     51     79
    66     105    27
```

I want that the first row will be the row that the first element is more higher than the second and the third elements in his row.
the second row will be the row that the second element is more higher than the first and third elements in his row.
and the third row will be the row that the second element is more higher than the first and the second elements in his row.

for the example, the result is:

```
mat =
    129    14    20      (because 129 > 14 and 129 > 20)
    66     105   27      (105 > 66 and 105 > 27)
    42     51    79      (79 > 51 and 79 > 42)
```

I know I can pass the elements of the matrix and do that, but may the function 'sort' includes something that helps me?

Comment: This is kind of a strange thing to do.  What's your application?

Comment: I need to multiply the result matrix by a transformation matrix. my transformation matrix is from matrix1 to the matrix2: [ 255 0 0; 0 255 0; 0 0 255], so I have matrix1 to be sorted by the condition. thank for your reply!

Comment: You'll notice that the matrix [255 0 0; 0 255 0; 0 0 255] behaves the same way as the scalar 255.

Comment: @nibot, you are right! thank you. if you can, please look in my other topic that explain you why I need it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843188/matlab-restoring-the-image-to-its-original-colors
do you know what I should do with the negative values? it's not good for the rgb :/

Comment: @AlonShmiel: I've rolled back your edit, since otherwise, the question doesn't fit at all with the accepted answer. Please create a new question if you need help on the other issue (though it seemed rather mathematical, so maybe you want to do it over at math.stackexchange).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mat = [ 129    14     20
         42    51     79
         66   105    27];

[Y,I] = max(mat, [], 2);

mat = mat(I, :)
```